# How does weapon durability work in Fates?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

There seems to be a big difference between Fates and the other Fire Emblem games, my weapons don't seem to have a number next to them telling me how many uses I have left.

Staves, however, seem to still have limited usage.

Did they just get rid of weapon durability or does it work differently now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct, weapon durability does not exist in Fates (for any path - Birthright,  Conquest or Revelations). Staves however, do have limited number of uses; the stave will go away after it's all used up. In the Birthright and Conquest paths, there is no way to combine Staves into a single item with more uses; staves can be combined in Revelations.

Comment: adding to this, now the more damage a weapon does, the less accuracy it has (in general). This or follow ups attacks are reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they just got rid of the weapon of durability and they did that for a reason!

Instead of making us concentrate on the durability of your weapon and if yes or no it is a good moment to use my best weapons, they instead wanted to make us focus on what is the most important effect you want in your following attacks. Do you want a follow-up attack? Do you want sacrifice damage for more chance to avoid a counter-attack with a Bronze weapon? Would you take the risk to hit with a silver weapon when you know that your stats will drop for the next turn? Those are the kind of questions that will matter instead of weapon durability.

Also, although the concept of infinite durability of every weapons (except staves) seems as ''completly'' different from the rest of the Fire Emblem series, it was in fact in the second Fire Emblem of the entire series ''Fire Emblem Gaiden'', which only got on Famicom systems, who showed this concept for the first time.